# How to pause and play a video with popcorn.js

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, dom-events, popcornjs

I'm trying to set up a video page where the video stops to play at 5 seconds automatically but I don't know how to do it with popcorn.js.

In addition, I need to set up a button to replay the video when the user clicks. I have the button but I don't know how to create an event to make the video play again.

If anyone knows how to do this, I would be really pleased, as I'm a film-maker and not a programmer and I'm lost with Javascript.

I'm open to return the favor. If you need anything about video editing or production or animation, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by leveraging the `timeupdate` event of the video element. Let's assume your video element on the page is named `video`, the code would look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('video').timeupdate = function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    if (video.currentTime == 5) {
        video.pause();
    }
};
```

then with the button you can just attach to the `onclick` event and play the video:

```
document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
}
```